# Adding Collection of SPUsers into SPGroup

Tags: sharepoint, spuser, spgroup

We can add an `SPUser` into an `SPGroup` by `objSPGroup.Users.Add(objSPUser)`.  I need to add `SPUserCollection` into one `SPGroup`.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

`SPGroup` [actually contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.users.aspx) an `SPUserCollection` object, representing the containing users. I don't see how you could overload this. There also isn't any [method to add a full SPUserCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup_members.aspx) to a `SPGroup`.

What I think you are best of doing is to iterate through `SPUserCollection.GetCollection` ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercollection.getcollection.aspx)) users and adding them one by one to your `SPGroup`

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate to add an extension method to the SPGroup or the SPUserCollection